# How to implementing Repository patten with entity frame work mvc

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

i am trying to implement repository pattern in mvc. but I am stuck. I want to return related data. I have two classes , tbl_Account (contains users )and tbl_Country (contains countries).

```
    public class AccountRepository : IAccount
    {
    public IEnumerable<Account> GetCountry()
    {

       var Account = this.storeDB.tbl_UserAccount.Include(s => s.tbl_Country).ToList();
        
       return Account; // it gives error here, saying explicit cast required
    }
    }
```

Account is a model class i have created on top of tbl_Account for field validations.

how to cast this or i am missing something else... please please help

Answer (score 0):

1.) Variable name must start lower case.

2.) Method name 'GetCountry' but you return Account.

3.) After include you need to `Select` countries in account and then return countries.

4.) Please share your entities (model classes) in your question if you wanna get cool answers